# Connection does not complete in TCP LwIP

Tags: c, networking, tcp, stm32, lwip

I am trying to create a tcp connection with my board and my computer. I send a tcp packet from my computer initially using the tcp_connect() function. In the wireshark, it shows that the first handshake packet is sent by the board, but my computer returns a tcp packet with RST and ACK flag set. i searched about this, turns out it terminates the connection. and after that all i see is destination port unreachable messages.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
extern struct netif gnetif;
struct tcp_pcb* tcp_echoserver_pcb;
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  ip_addr_t myIPADDR,destip;
  IP_ADDR4(&myIPADDR,192,168,33,1);
  IP_ADDR4(&destip,192,168,33,101);

  tcp_echoserver_pcb = tcp_new();

  err_t err = tcp_bind(tcp_echoserver_pcb, &myIPADDR, 8);

  err_t e = tcp_connect(tcp_echoserver_pcb, &destip, 8, confail);

  if (e == ERR_RTE)
  {
      while(1)
      {
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LD3_Pin);
          HAL_Delay(500);
      }
  }

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      ethernetif_input(&gnetif);
      sys_check_timeouts();
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

through debugger I realized that the connect function returns routing error, but the error block only executes when in debugger mode. When executing normally, the control never enters the if(e == ERR_RTE) block .

thank you and please help and let me know if you need any additional information regarding my problem.

Comment: If the board is the server it has to listen() to and accept() incoming connections.

Comment: @HS2. The board is client and is trying to connect to the server(my PC).